# What is the reporting tool that you would use?

Tags: c#, printing, report

I need a tool that handle both on-screen and printed reports, via my C# application.

I'm looking for simple, standard and powerful.

I need to be able to give the user the ability to select which columns to display, formatting, etc... with my own GUI and dynamically build the report based upon their choices. Crystal does not fit the bill here because the columns cannot be added on the fly (and the column widths can not be adjusted on the fly).

I'm thinking of using HTML with the WebBrowser control in my app, but I will have very little control over printing and print preview.

Another option is go to .NET 3.5 (I'm using 2.0) and use XAML with Flow Documents.

What would you use?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how Crystal Reports is not dynamic enough?  What are you trying to do that CR can't do?

Comment: You might want to rephrase the question, Jason. Most users of SO contend that there is no "best" anything, and we try to avoid platform wars. At most you should ask "what reporting tool should I use?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use SQL reporting services. HTML reports have their place but you dont get very much controlling over formatting.

SQL reporting services summary:

Advantages:
Basic version is free
Included with SQL express
Many exporting options pdf, html, csv etc
Can use many different datasources
Webservice which exposes various methods
SQL standard editon includes a report builder component to allow users create and share their own reports
Lots of features for querying formatting etc
Scheduling options
Extensibility import .net framework dlls for custom functionality
Familiar microsoft environment

Disadvantages:
An extra thing to setup
Seemless authentication between application and report server can be a pain depending on your setup
A little bit of a learning curve although its not too hard to pick up 
Report model creator needs some work and doesnt automatically a-z fields

I have heard good things about DevXpress so may be worth looking into.

I used Crystal about 5 years ago and remember it being a pain to setup and was costly licence wise.

Comment: I need a client-side solution, and I think SQL Reporting Services has the same limitations on dynamic creation that Crystal has.

Comment: Do your clients have internet connectivity?

Comment: Yes, but online reports are not acceptable. The point of the fat client is to have the reports there. It is my clients requirement, not mine. Online reports are done already.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Report Viewer stuff in studio 2008 / .NET 3.5

This amazing site has the full scoop:
[GotReportViewer](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/)

It's a nice build in reporting system that will show a report and print.  It's not full blown like Crystal or SQL Reporting Services.  If all you need is some lightweight reporting you can't beat the price.

Comment: Kudos for this site. Used the code to build a complete generic web based report builder. Should put the code up for an opensource project.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal = Big footprint, huge deployment, fast, good designer and support
MS ReportViewer = small footprint, slow, bad designer, support.. well, not so damn easy to search after reportviewer, a name all uses.. sigh.

Comment: I actually find the report designer in reporint services very easy to use and can get it to do most things. I also don't think performance is that slow. The only times I have had trouble have been embedding reports in pages. In contrast I find crystal to be very tempremental.

Comment: Interresting.. I'm using the designer inside Visual Studio, and have one report with about 300 cells in an table, that report alone uses 1min 35 seconds only to open in design...
The executing performance is excelent though.
But if you get around 800 pages.. it get problems, which crystal did not..

Answer (score 1):

We use [ActiveReports.net](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/ProductOverview.aspx?Product=ARNET3) here. They're OK and tend to get the job done pretty well, but I'm not sure if they would fit your definition of "Dynamic". But you can pretty much make them do anything though code.

Comment: i love active reports - the ability to render any .net control to the report surface is a stellar feature!

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently considering DevXpress XtraReports as a replacement for CR. So far I like what I see.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Reporting Services probably aren't flexible enough for what you want as you don't really get a deep level of code manipulation.

Active reports let you get into the binding events and pretty much do whatever you want, however there are a couple of small bugs with active reports (like not being able to bind to a defaultview of a datatable) which make it a pain. Apart from that, it's highly flexible.

XtraReports are awesome but they're a lot pricier than Active Reports. Having said that, their support is fantastic and the reporting package is rock solid. I'd look at forking out the cash for them if possible.