# What tool to use to create reports in c#?

Tags: c#, report

Which tool is recommended to write a report in c#?

My impression was that Reporting services are a good tool and easy to use, but in the same time it is sometimes hard to create more complex reports that have to present data in not very standard way (following client requirements).
For this cases I used MSChart, I think it is possible to create larger verity of reports but it seemed to be less intuitive, and although I eventually got to the desired results, I had many limitations, and things that are not built-in as in the Reporting Services.
Are there any other recommended tools?

Comment: You can try CrystalReports or Telerik Reporting tools

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the reporting tool that you would use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164492/what-is-the-reporting-tool-that-you-would-use) This question has been asked here on SO very often in several variations, and the answer is: there are dozens of options, free ones, commercial ones, ones utilizing MS Office etc. etc. etc.

Comment: It is very hard to say which is suitable to you. Try to search most popular reporting tools and review(or even better try) them by your self, because just you know what you exactly need. Also you can check DevExpress and Stimulsoft reporting tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSChart is good reporting tool, but there are some more tools like [Crystal Reports](http://crystalreports.com/), [Reporting Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/reporting-services.aspx), [Telerik Reporting](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx) and [DevExpress's XtraReport](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/). Try to use a tool that has a big user community, otherwise it will be difficult to use and understand because there won't be much help available online.

Crystal Reports can be used as they have good compatibility with MS Visual Studio, and a lot of people are using this tool. They have a good online support and community available if you need any help. Great documentation. You can also use DevExpress's XtraReport because it gives nice look and feel, It comes with many customizable options by default, such as exporting the report to pdf format, adding watermark..., keep in mind its not free.

So there are a lot of options available out in the market, you just have to decide which fulfills your requirements.

Comment: Several of my coworkers are often expressing great frustration with Crystal Reports, so I would probably try out some of the other tools first.

Comment: Nothing is always Perfect, if you found some thing not filling your needs you can try its alternate. there are many other alternates available. i've listed some of them above.

Answer (score 0):

I would use .NET and install iTextSharp
Its very rich and you can do everything programmilly.